# does $\lim_{b \to a }(\lim_{x \to b } f(x))=\lim_{x \to a } f(x)$?

Tags: limits

does $\displaystyle \lim_{b \to a }(\lim_{x \to b } f(x))=\lim_{x \to a } f(x)$?

Comment: Not necessarily, consider a function with a removable discontinuity. (i.e. a hole)

Comment: (Responding to edits) Try rewriting with $y$ instead of $b$ and see if that helps you to understand the problem. I think you may have it stuck in your head that $b$ is constant

Comment: yes, OK. I get that now.

Comment: I don't see how a removable discontinuity could make the equality invalid. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Actually my apologies, I confused myself a little as well. I've been up for a bit and for some reason I thought of a counterexample for if the right-hand side was $f(a).$ Now I think it could be true but I've got to try some stuff

Comment: Ok I think I've found a functional counterexample now, but it's a bit less trivial so I don't think I could comfortably just tell you. But as a hint, the idea is that limits care about the behavior around a given point rather than at it, so we want the limit of the function approaching a point to behave differently everywhere around a given point than it does actually at a point. If you've done certain real analysis problems regarding limits at points, then hopefully this will bring to mind certain ways of constructing a function whose limit only behaves at a single given point.